# Unique item ID that is not changed when item is moved

Tags: exchangewebservices

Is any item ID or properties which are:
1. not changed when an item is moved
2. changed when an item is updated?

I tried to use PidTagSearchKey+PidTagChangeKey, PidTagSearchKey+PidTagLastModifiedTime. Unfortunately PidTagChangeKey and PidTagLastModifiedTime are changed when an item is moved.

Answer (score 0):

PidTagSearchKey won't change when you move or copy a Messages between folder (so whats the problem with just using that property?), it will be the same on a Message that is copied. The IntenetMessageId would be another property that should be unique but will can be duplicated if a message is copied rather then moved.

Comment: PidTagSearchKey is not updated when an item is changed. For example, if I change an appointment or draft message, PidTagSearchKey is not updated. IntenetMessageId exists for emails only and is also not updated when message is changed.

Comment: If we copy an item, then change one of them, we will get two items with different properties and the same PidTagSearchKey, will not we?

Comment: A move is a change but I can't see any reason why you can't make the logic work for you with the existing properties.

Comment: Of course, I can make the program logic. But without properties that satisfy the conditions of the original question, it will be more difficult. In any case, thank you, Glen.